# AQFT: Can test functions obey the Klein-Gordon equation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In AQFT we can choose test functions with compact support. Can such functions obey a Klein-Gordon equation?

I start with a test function $g$ with compact support and I apply the Klein-Gordon operator: $\mathrm{KG}(g) = f$. I can use the advanced and retarded Green's functions to get solutions  $g_1$ and $g_2$ such that
$$\mathrm{KG}(g_1) = \mathrm{KG}(g_2) = f$$
and so $\mathrm{KG}(g_1 - g_2) = 0$.

If my $g$ (with compact support) was $g_1$, I get $g - g_2$ which obey the KG equation but what about the support of $g_2$?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is.  So, you take the equation $\mathrm{KG}(g) = f$ and obtain two solutions $g_1,g_2$. Are you asking that if $\mathrm{KG}(g_1-g_2) = 0$, this implies the support of $g_2$ is compact if that of $g_1$ was?

Comment: The general question is can an infinitely derivable function f(x,y,z,t) with compact support obey KG(f(x,y,z,t) = 0.

Comment: Then i tell what i tried I take as g1 a test function with finite support such that the retarded green's function operating on KG (g1) gives back g1.

Comment: The advanced green's function  on KG(g1) giving g2, g1-g2 obey KG, supp(g1) is finite but i cannot say that supp (g1 - g2) is compact.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why this does not depend of the choice of the Cauchy surface?

Answer (score 5):

No, they cannot. There is no non-vanishing smooth KG solution with compact support. Let $\psi$ be a compactly supported solution (I assume $m>0$, the massless case is a bit more complicated) and $T_{ab}$ the associated stress energy tensor. The integral of $T_{00}\geq 0$ over a spacelike Cauchy surface at constant Minkowski time, $\Sigma$, does not depend on the chosen Cauchy surface.

Since the support of $\psi$ is compact we can fix $\Sigma$ far away from the support of $\psi$, obtaining $\int_\Sigma T_{00} d^3x =0$ on $\Sigma$ which, in turn, implies that 
$T_{00}|_\Sigma=0$ (because $T_{00}\geq 0$) and thus
both $\psi$ and $\partial_0\psi$ vanishes on $\Sigma$ just in view of the form of $T_{00}$ ($m>0$). Since $\Sigma$ is a Cauchy surface, we have that $\psi=0$ everywhere in the spacetime.
Dealing with a generic globally hyperbolic spacetime you can rearrange this proof.

**ADDENDUM**. If $m=0$, the condition $T_{00}|_\Sigma =0$ implies $\partial_0\psi|_\Sigma=0$ and $\partial_k\psi|_\Sigma=0$ for $k=1,2,3$, referring to Minkowskian coordinates adapted to $\Sigma$ (thus corresponding to $t=t_0$).
Consequently $\psi$ is constant over $\Sigma$. Since the support of $\psi|_\Sigma$ is compact as well, it must be $\psi|_\Sigma=0$ reducing to the previously treated case.

Comment: What choice of Cauchy surface would never intersect with the support of the function?

Comment: Also are we talking about compact support in $M$ or compact support in $\Sigma$?

Comment: I am not sure to  understand your question. As the spacetime is globally hyperbolic, it is diffeomorphic to the product $\mathbb R \times S$ for every given Cauchy surface $S$. Since the support of $\psi$ is compact, in that Cartesian support $K$ of  the continuous function $t$ varying in the factor $\mathbb R$ and labeling the Cauchy surfaces $S_t$ must assume, e.g.,, a minimal value $u$ on $K$.

Comment: Ah, so it is compact with respect to the entire spacetime. I was thinking about a function with compact support on some initial condition.

Comment: Every $S_t$ with $t<u$ cannot intersect $K$. A similar result holds for sufficiently large positive values of $t$.

Comment: Yes I meant compact w.r.to  the entire spacetime.

Comment: @ValterMoretti but compact initial data is fine? So the solution is not compact because the causal propagator "propagates" the data into a non-compact subset of $M$?

Comment: Yes, roughly speaking...